# Isolation of points: The meaning in topology vs complex analysis?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

For example: Munkres Topology Problem 27.6:

[image]

I am having a little difficulty understanding what it means for a one point set to be open.  A set is open if its complement in a compact set is closed.  Since we delete open sets at every step of the construction of the Cantor set, that which remains is closed, so the points are not isolated.  I am having difficulty envisioning a counter case.

For instance, we say the zeros of non-constant holomorphic functions are isolated.  Is that isolation meant in a different sense in complex analysis?  Is the complex plane a "space?"  Isn't the one-point set of a zero of holomorphic function a closed set, meaning it is not isolated in the topological sense?

Comment: If you take the space $\{0\} \cup [2,3]$ with the induced topology from the usual real topology then the point $0$ is isolated because the set $B(0,1) = \{0\}$ is open. The above is just saying that if $U$ is open and contains $c \in C$ then $U \setminus \{c\}$ contains other points of $C$.

Comment: It means $B(x,r) = \{ y | d(x,y) <r \}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Could you say a little more about "the usual real topology?"  Why is the ball open?  Is "B" defined as an open ball?

Comment: The usual topology on the reals is that you get from the norm $|x|$. So, for example, in the reals $B(0,1) = (-1,1)$. Does this address your question?

Comment: Why is the ball that contains only zero open rather than closed?

Comment: Are you familiar with the topology induced on a subset?

Comment: I would say that I am but you are probably correct to conclude that I am not.  Could you tell me why it is open, please?

Comment: If $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ then we say that $U $ is open in $X$ **iff** there is some $U'$ that is open in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $U= U'\ \cap X$.  In my example in the first comment, the set $\{0\}$ is open in $X=\{0\} \cup [2,3]$ because $(-1,1) \cap X = \{0\}$. (It is also closed.)

Comment: I see.  I think it being both open and closed was the issue that was confusing me the most.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most intuitive way of thinking about isolated points is as follows.
Let $S$ be a subset of some space $X$ and $s\in S$.
We say $s$ is isolated in $S$ if there is some neighborhood $V\subset X$ of $s$ with $V\cap S = \{s\}$.
In other words, there are no other points of $S$ 'arbitrarily close' to $s$.

When we say the zeroes of a holomorphic function $f$ are isolated, we mean that around each root $r$ one can find a ball $B$ such that the only root of $f$ in $B$ is $r$.

For the Cantor set, any ball around any point $p$ in the Cantor set will contain infinitely many other points in the Cantor set.
Hence, no point in the Cantor set is isolated.

Comment: Consider a closed one point set.  There is a disc around the point that does not contain any other points.  The disc definition says it is isolated but the Munkres definition says it is not isolated because it is not open.  What is the discrepancy?

Comment: They agree. The intersection of the disk and $X$ is $\{x\}$, so $\{x\}$ is open **in $X$**. $\{x\}$ may fail to be open in the ambient space, but that's okay.

Comment: "The intersection of the disk and X is {x}, so {x} is open in X."  This must get to the important point which I am failing to understand.  How does it follow that {x} is open in X?

Comment: This is the [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology). Given an (ambient) topological space $T$ and a subspace $S\subset T$, the subspace topology on $S$ (induced by $T$) is as follows: each subset of $S$ is open if and only if it is the intersection of an open subset of $T$ with $S$.

Comment: If the disk in open in the ambient space $\Bbb R$ and its intersection with $X\subset \Bbb R$ is $\{x\}$, then $\{x\}$ is open in $X$ (with the subspace topology).